# WCF with Android (TCPBinding) and ServiceStack

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android, servicestack

I'm investigation different options to access remote data for an Android application(in the future WindowsEmbedded and possibly iOS with monotouch), so I've made some tests and I'm trying to understand what is possible and is not possible to do.

I already have a client(WindowsCE)/server(win32) solution that uses raw sockets. I'll rewrite the server with .NET,and for communication I would like to try WCF.
I wrote a simple WCF .NET server application, and connected to it with basicHTTPBinding with Android, and it works.
But for performance reasons I want to use TCPBinding, and I got stuck with svcutil etc etc, and I can't understand if I'm unable to do it or if is not possible.
Is WCF fully, partially, going to be fully supported in mono for android?

If the answer is no, and I cannot use binary TCP binding with WCF, what would it be the advantage of moving to ServiceStack (havent't tested yet, but seems to be considered better than WCF).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally wouldn't try to use WCF on embedded devices, especially on Mono where it only has partial support of the WCF Stack. Also the default binary serializer used in WCF tcp binding is actually both [slow and requires a larger payload than most serializers](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/09/protobuf-net-vs-netdatacontractserializ.html):

#### ProtoBuf

- Size (bytes): 133,010
- Serialize (ms): 10,769
- DeSerialize (ms): 23,511

#### NetDataContractSerializer (WCF Binary)

- Size (bytes): 992,203
- Serialize (ms): 29,343
- DeSerialize (ms): 91,453

Currently for the best performance in ServiceStack you can enable .NET's fastest binary formats via NuGet plugins, see:

- [ProtoBuf](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format)
- [Message Pack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MessagePack-Format)

The nice thing about using ServiceStack is because all the [typed C# Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) share the same interfaces you can easily develop with a flexible and debugger friendly format like JSON ([which is also fast](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/#burningmonk-benchmarks)) and then when you're done development, easily switch over to one of the binary formats above for maximum performance.

### Future TCP Endpoint support planned for ServiceStack

Because [ServiceStack's Architecture](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview) makes it easy to support multiple endpoints, we also plan on enabling a fast TCP Endpoint after we've merged our [async branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commits/async). It will work transparently like our other ServiceClients so will be just as easy to switch to by using another ServiceClient.

Comment: Thanks again, ServiceStack seems the way to go.
My only issue is that the current software (a healthcare application on CE5/WindowsMobile made with .NET Compact Framework 3.5,used in hospitals) uses raw sockets, and it's the one I need to update first, that's why I chose WCF. But I want to keep the door open for possible Android or IPad versions.
WCF seems badly supported on Mono, and ServiceStack seems not supported on .NET Compact Framework...

Comment: Yeah ServiceStack clients don't support .NET CF so you'll need to fallback to using a HTTP Client + JSON serializer (or ProtoBuf, etc) that does support .NET CF.

Comment: So do you think I can still create a ServiceStack based server and connect to it with a REST library compatible with .NET CF, and with ServiceStack on Mono clients?
Another question: is there a way to know the progress of the download of the webservice response?
I mean, if the answer is 1MB, can I know the progression and show a progressbar?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as ServiceStack just returns Plain old XML, JSON or ProtoBuf, etc. Any compatible .NET CF HTTP Client + Serializer can consume it. You would need to make your own HTTP Request using Async APIs to be able to get notified of download progress.

Comment: Id avoid proto buffers like the plague if you communicate to other systems or externals.  NetDataContract can be used cross system but is proprietary. And if you dont use namespaces and 4.5 Compression then net.tcp is pretty small - not as small  but at least you wont have many cross system issues as its self describing unlike proto buffers.